# How to programatically run custom command for specific schema using django-tenants?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-commands, django-tenants

I am new with django-tenants. I want to programatically run a cummand I have created with `management.call_command()` but I am getting error. Can someone help me with this?

This command runs without error. I want to achieve same programatically.

```
python manage.py tenant_command load_some_data --schema=<schema_name>
```

my code:

`call_command('tenant_command', 'load_user_groups', schema_name=schema_name)`
I get following error:

```
 File "/home/stackuser/Desktop/DjangoPr/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 114, in call_command
    app_name = get_commands()[command_name]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Can you please share the *full* traceback?